# How can I connect consul with cloudflare?

Tags: key-value, cloudflare, consul

I am building a Cloudflare worker project (with wrangler).

My requirement is when customer hits URL for my project.
(say it is "example.com"),

the worker code should read the consul key-values (where I have the IP addresses stored), and then redirect customer to that IP address.

I may use consul-templates to do the task, but seems like it will increase the latency.

---

Long story short ..

What is the best way to connect Cloudflare to consul
and read consul key-values ? (also keep a watch on consul key-value changes)